# Clean and Build a solution without using Visual Studio

Tags: .net, .net-core

How can I perform these 2 tasks without opening Visual Studio:

1. Clean a Solution.
2. Build a Solution.

The Solution may be using .NET Standard and/or .NET Core.

**Note: I want to create a batch file in (Windows cmd or PowerShell) to perform these tasks. I may not know if the Solution is using .NET Standard or .NET Core or both.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be able to use command line with the command

`dotnet build --no-incremental`

or use

`dotnet clean` then `dotnet build` separately.

Docs:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-clean

Answer (score 1):

For .net core you can use [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-clean)

```
dotnet clean
```

For msbuild, you can create a target `Clean` and then call this target from the commandline: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-clean-a-build?view=vs-2019)

```
 <Target Name = "Clean">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(builtdir)" />
</Target>

msbuild <file name>.proj -target:Clean
```